# Connecting Inputs and Outputs of Transfer Function Models

Tags: control-systems

I am trying to use Mathematica's `TransferFunctionModel` object and `SystemsModelFeedbackConnect` function to approach the following coupled control problem

[image: A conceptual block flow diagram]

A version of the above BFD that looks like the code is below.

[image: A programmatical block flow diagram]

I make use of [`SystemsModelFeedbackConnect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemsModelFeedbackConnect.html). It is not possible to link any output to any input, but that they must be the same index. It also isn't possible to specify the feedback type of the output of system 1 to input of system 2 but it is possible to specify the feedback type of the output of system 2 to the input of system 1. I am under the impression that with the below I get away with the problem, assuming that the output of system 1 to input of system 2 is negative feedback and changing the sign on the matrix accordingly. But the system is divergent.

```
g11 = 3./(2. s + 1);
g12 = -10.;
g21 = 1/(s^2 + 3. s + 2.);
g22 = 4./((s + 1) (3. s + 1));
gc11 = kc11 (1 + 1/(tI11 s));
gc22 = kc22 (1 + 1/(tI22 s));
kc11 = 0.1; kc22 = 0.1; tI11 = 0.1; tI22 = 0.1;
sys1TF = TransferFunctionModel[{{gc11 g11 , g12}, {-gc11, -0}}, (* negative due to forced negative feed back *)
  s]; (* input 1 is e1, input 2 is u2, output 1 is y1, output 2 is u1 *)
sys2TF = TransferFunctionModel[{{gc22 g22, g21}, {gc22, 0}}, 
  s]; (* input 1 is e2, input 2 is u1, output 1 is y2, output 2 is u2 *)
recSys1TF = 
 SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[
  sys1TF, {1, 1, 
   "Negative"}]; (* only recycle the first output to the first input *)


recSys2TF = 
 SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[
  sys2TF, {1, 1, 
   "Negative"}]; (* only recycle the first output to the first input *)


totalTF = SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[recSys1TF, recSys2TF,
  {2}, (* 
  connect output 2 of system 1 to input 2 of system 2 by negative 
feedback *)
  {{2, "Positive"}} (* 
  connect output 2 of system 2 to input 2 of system 1 by addition*)
  ];
```

The current formulation may either be outright incorrect or just extremely unstable due to the high order of the transfer function model. The question I have is, why can only pairs of index corresponding inputs and outputs can be fed? Looking at [`SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect.html) it is possible to connect any input to any output. Is this a result of a limitation of the `TransferFunctionModel` in contrast to the `StateSpaceModel`?

Comment: For what I understand the help of `SystemsModelFeedbackConnect`you're connecting output2 of recSys1 with input1 of recSys2 (positive feedback, as in the image in the detail section, and no further input from outside), and you're connecting output1 of recSys2 with input2 of recSys1, positive feedback. It's like in your picture. I think youre picture does not match your comments in the code. But that's just how I understood the help section.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an answer, but this way I can show with some image, how I unterstood the help of `SystemsModelFeedbackConnect`.

It's all about this section:
[image]

With

```
SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[sys1,sys2,{2,1},{{2,"Negative"},{1,"Positive"}}]
```

I connect my systems like in the following picture:
[image]

D to G, C to H (no additional input at G and H, and no choice of feedback),

and F to A (positive) and E to B (negative). There are no additional outputs at E and F.

Your resulting system is 2x2.

What you were trying was something like

```
SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[sys1,sys2,{2},{{2,"Negative"}}]
```

You might would expect 3 outputs and 3 inputs, because you only connected just one of them to the other.
But the dimensions of this resulting system are 2x2, too.

But it could be I totaly missunterstood the whole thing.